# Why did the Predator choose to kill drug dealers instead of the police when both sides were fully armed?

Tags: plot-explanation, predator-2

In a scene from the movie *Predator 2* (1990) we can see the police and drug dealers having a gun fight. In this scene the police and also the drug dealers are well armed with weapons. After the fight the Predator attacks and kills all of the drug dealers. The police also was a very easy target for the Predator at that time.

So why did the Predator choose to kill the drug dealers instead of the police even though both sides were fully armed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because Predator goes for the best ones not the easiest ones.

The drug dealers were easily outshooting police. Until they shot the first dealer the cops had around 7 wounded on their side.

We assume that when Danny Glover's character shot the remaining dealers with a shotgun the predators was already in a different place making an ambush so he only knew about the abilities of those who he hunted.